# ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01003: no statement parsed

Tags: java, oracle

From this code:

```
try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                CallableStatement callableStatement = prepareCallableStatement(connection, pqTO,connection.prepareCall(QUERY));
                ResultSet resultSet = ResultSetHelper.prepareResultSet(callableStatement, 49)
                ){
```

I am getting

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01003: no statement parsed
```

The expectation is to get value with `'` such as `ABC'xyz`, which I was getting but at `ResultSet` I am getting the exception. I don't want to remove `'` neither we can remove it from the database, but I need to send value as it is to UI.

I tried split and replace but the main objective is that we need this value with `'`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: this work fine for other values with out " ` "

Comment: which character you have `'` or ` ?

Comment: Escape the quote with another quote.

Comment: Would you please post the query? What the query is doing?

Comment: Where does JavaScript fit it? What is the actual query? Are you embedding a string passed from the UI in that query string - and if so, why are you doing that instead of using bind variables?

Comment: You might also need to explain, in your question, what `ResultSetHandler` is and what `prepareResultSet` is doing. Those seem to be your own, or part of your existing project anyway?

Comment: What exactly does `QUERY` contain? And what exactly does your `prepareCallableStatement()` function do?

Comment: QUERY IS : SELECT * FROM PQ  where origin_code =org_code and destination_code=des_code; name of origin contain special character when result is return from db to java layer i am getting this error .

Comment: i have added debug and  found that error is before the result set the  because of that special character other wise query is working fine as per the expectation

Comment: QUERY IS : SELECT * FROM PQ  where origin_code =org_code and destination_code=des_code; name of origin  which is separate column apart from where condition parameter contain special character when result is return from db to java layer i am getting this error .

Comment: please provide any solution …….!